# Laravel not inserting data into one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have two tables student and subject and there is a one to many relation , because one subject can contain many students. And one student can only contain one subject.But in my database seeding is inserting data (except the subject id).
My student.php

```
protected $fillable=['name','username','password','interest','email','gender','image'];
public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
    }
```

Subject.php

```
protected $fillable=['name','department_id'];
 public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class,'interest');
    }
```

And here is my seeder

```
public function run()
    {
        $subject = new Subject;
        $subject->name="Software";
        $subject->save();
        $student=Student::create([
                'name' =>  Str::random(6),
                'email' =>  Str::random(6).'@gmail.com',
                'username' => Str::random(6),
                'password' => bcrypt('tanvir'),
                'phone' =>  rand(),
                'gender' => Str::random(6),
                'image' => bcrypt('tanvir'),
            ]);
        $student->subject()->associate($subject);
    }
```

And here is my migrations file

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password')->unique();
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('interest')->nullable();
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('interest')
                ->references('id')->on('subjects')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('department_id')
                ->references('id')->on('departments')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

Database seeding working but subject id is not saving in my student table on interest column.Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not following the convention I believe that Laravel does not know how to connect your user to the subject.. So can you try this please:

```
public function subject()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class, 'interest');
}
```

Laravel expects that the foreign key is `subject_id`, but it is `interest`, so you need to let Laravel know.

**EDIT**

```
$student = Student::create([
   'name' =>  Str::random(6),
   'email' =>  Str::random(6).'@gmail.com',
   'username' => Str::random(6),
   'password' => bcrypt('tanvir'),
   'phone' =>  rand(),
   'gender' => Str::random(6),
   'image' => bcrypt('tanvir'),
   'interest' => $subject->id
]);
```

Comment: still it is not inserting

Comment: and why not use `'interest' => $subject->id` as you already have the `interest` in the `$fillable` array :) so add this in your `create()` call.

Comment: I didn't mentioned `cast` but take a look at my edit :) And just one question mark is enough, many question marks makes the comment sound like you are angry at me :D